# Possible to load Google Drive spreadsheet as JSON without consent screen?

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to implement a JSON feed to my site straight from a private (only those with the link can access) spreadsheet. I need to generate a new auth token using OAuth 2.0 which is fine, but it seems that Google Sheets API v4 requires that "auth" screen. That way the data is either loaded as JSON or it isn't loaded at all.
Is there any setting or override I can set in so that I don't have to have that pesky intermediate step? I don't need to access any of the user's files... just the feed for this specific spreadsheet using OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheetsv4 [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing) mentions that there are two ways of authorizing requests when using Google Sheets. They are using oauth token and API key:

> When your application requests private data, the request must be
>   authorized by an authenticated user who has access to that data.
>
> When your application requests public data, the request doesn't need
>   to be authorized, but does need to be accompanied by an identifier,
>   such as an API key.
>
> Every request your application sends to the Google Sheets API needs to
>   identify your application to Google. There are two ways to identify
>   your application: [using an OAuth
>   2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#AboutAuthorization)
>   token (which also authorizes the request) and/or using the
>   application's [API
>   key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#APIKey).
>   Here's how to determine which of those options to use:
>
> If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an
>   individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth
>   2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to. If the request doesn't require
>   authorization (such as a request for public data), then the
>   application must provide either the API key or an OAuth 2.0 token, or
>   both—whatever option is most convenient for you.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer, even though you didn't see the part in my question where I said the data is private, so unfortunately API key is not an option. I will be using a service account instead.